# Why this script is working but my cron isn't?

Tags: php, ssh, cron

I try to create a cron on a server (I should have right on it).

This is my script  `cron.php` :

```
<?php
    echo "CRON OK \n";
?>
```

I connect with SSH and create the following cron with `crontab -e` :

```
* * * * * php /home/myname/www/cron.php
```

But I don't know how to save it.. Anyway I save the crontab at the default location `/tmp/crontab.XAblsdZ/crontab`, the server tell me "crontab: installing new crontab" and when I execute `crontab -l` I can see `* * * * * php /home/myname/www/cron.php`.

I also try my script : `php /home/myname/www/cron.php`
The server display "CRON OK" so I guess it works.

But without this command I can't see any "CRON OK" displayed... Am I missing something ? How to enable this cron and execute my script every minute?

Comment: You have some possible errors described in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either add #!/usr/bin/php as suggested or you could add it to your crontab, make sure the /usr/bin/php is actually the right path to your PHP.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/myname/www/cron.php
```

The cron line looks good to execute every minute though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the beginning of your `cron.php`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```